# How do I change "Show Applications" button position from right to left?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

[image: Image of toolbar attached]
as you can see the **show applications** or dash button is on the right. I want to make it come to the left. how can I do that? My dock is at the bottom of the screen